# Sudo apt-get install in terminal asking for password

Tags: gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I'm using the AI Platform notebook and I want to install cuda because the Tensorflow can't use GPU.

```
sudo apt-get install cuda-cudart-10-0
```

Then in the command line it's asking me for password.

```
(base) jupyter@cuda-10-1-20201008-115420:~/tutorials/stylegan2$ sudo apt-get install cuda-cudart-10-0

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

[sudo] password for jupyter: 
Sorry, try again.
```

I don't recall I gave it any password while setting it up. Is there a default password for it?

Comment: It is asking for *your* user password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the first question, our Notebooks provide TensorFlow and when you create it, you can select to install Nvidia Driver automatically. Probably this option was missed during instance creation.

With respect to the second question, from the output, seems to be that you are in Jupyter Terminal.
Jupyter Notebooks provides access to Instance OS which could be Debian 9/10 or we support Ubuntu now. Jupyter Terminal process is running as jupyter user. While you can still run process as root. I would suggest you that you login via SSH and run commands directly from there. If you create the Notebook via UI we now provide OS login feature which allows you to access instance via SSH with IAM permissions hence your Google Cloud user account. If you are not sure of any of this, please contact your IT admin.

Answer (score -1):

What do you think `sudo` does? If this is your first time using a Linux system, know that prepending every command in Linux with `sudo` is same as typing `cmd` in the windows run box and then pressing `shift+enter`. `sudo` is a way to tell the OS that I need admin rights (or in Linux's case, root permissions). So, it is bound to ask you for the password.

The password it is asking for is your account password. Also, it is usually a good idea to set up the root password when in first use. To set it up, drop into the root prompt from your user account using `sudo su`. Then type in `passwd` to set up a new password for the root user. Log out, and restart the machine.

Do not forget that root account has the ultimate privileges, and unless absolutely necessary, it is always better to prepend the command with sudo instead of dropping into the root prompt.

> PS: A hint: `sudo <command>` followed by the caller's password is same as `su -c '<command>'` followed by the root account's password

---

You also might want to take a look at [`fakeroot`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/fakeroot-tcp.1.html)

Comment: I know what is sudo, I used sudo su but it still asked me for my password. It's a created compute engine so I have no password. Either there is default password.

Comment: @ElonaMishmika Are you using an online cloud-based OS (like EC2), or have you installed the OS in your local machine?

Answer (score -2):

Which linux distro are you on? Like Kali has default password as `root` or `toor` or `kali` depending on version

Comment: It is not asking for the root password